# Today Edge animation is all scrambled in Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, animation, adobe-edge, capability

I had build a small html site that contained Adobe Edge animations about a year ago. 
Today I noticed that Chrome doesn't show it the way it did before. Object are out of place and some objects are missing.

Anyone out there worked with Edge animations and knows how to ensure browser capability?

Maybe some kind of workaround to make it stable. I've even considered just turning it into a video and getting rid of its interactivity, the animations are very inconsistent between browsers.

Any tips would be incredibly helpful.

Comment: This is really a website for help with code, not questions in general. The programmers overflow would be a better place to ask this question.

Comment: @EvanCarslake the question is one of debugging or implementation a specific problem - not the design of a solution.  It is off topic on Programmers.SE.

Comment: so no nothing? :( there is absolutely no info on this out there!

Comment: @MiaGilin consider putting information (screen shots, or links to them) about what shows up in chrome and what doesn't.  How are the objects out of place?  Could you include the associated code that renders that part of the scene?

Comment: I can't post just a part of code, the only way to see what's going on is to view the site, http://www.discovermuskoka. ca/web/crosscountry.html

If you view this site in Safari or latest IE and Firefox it looks fine. A year ago it looked great on Chrome as well but today all the element within the animation are all out of place. I understand chrome updates itself so I need to find a way to have it stay in one piece forever.